# Forking 'infinite' children in loop

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have some problems with a simple loop fork() program I'm trying to make and I need some help.

The thing is: I want a father and three children. Each children wait a random amount of time between 1 and 10 and then prints their PID. After that they die, but they are immediately replaced for other children which do the same, so in the end there are always three children printing their PIDs on screen. The father just print the number of children each 3 seconds.

That's what I want but the program is not working fine. Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int numero_procesos_hijos = 0;

void manejador_SIGCHLD(int sig)
{
    pid_t pid_hijo;
    int e;

    do {
        pid_hijo = wait3(&e, WNOHANG, NULL);
        if ((pid_hijo > (pid_t)0) && (WIFEXITED(e) || WIFSIGNALED(e)))
            numero_procesos_hijos--;
    } while (pid_hijo > (pid_t)0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid_hijo; 

    srand(time(NULL));
    fflush(NULL);

    if (signal(SIGCHLD, manejador_SIGCHLD) == SIG_ERR){
        perror("error en signal");
        exit(1);
    }

    do{
        if (numero_procesos_hijos < 3)
        {
            pid_hijo = fork();
            if (pid_hijo == -1){
                perror("Error en la creacion del fork");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (pid_hijo == 0){ /* Hijo */
                sleep(rand() % 10 + 1);
                printf("Soy el hijo con el PID %d\n", getpid());
            }

            numero_procesos_hijos++;
        }
        if (pid_hijo > 0){ /* Padre */
            sleep(3);
            printf("Numero procesos hijos: %d\n", numero_procesos_hijos);
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: Besides doing more in a signal-handler than is generally safe, it looks like you're not killing the child. Don't you need an `exit(0)` after the `printf` in the child block?

Comment: @ooga Dear God, I still don't know how I forgot to kill the child. Thanks mate.